# "The app didn't start" after adding Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently two days into this bug and can't seem to find the cause. I relatively recently installed VS2013 Update 2 RC and started building the Windows Phone 8.1 version of my WinRT app. I have been slowly moving files (mostly Converters/basic resources and pages) over to the Shared project and haven't had too many issues with it.

The Windows Phone 8.1 app builds and runs (though, with some issues that I still need to iron out). My WinRT app, which I haven't changed at all (except for some of its dependencies) aside from moving some things to the Shared project, will not start at all. It throws up "The app didn't start".

So far I've tried slowly moving files back out of the shared project and into the main WinRT project, but still to no avail. My hard drive is not encrypted with TrueCrypt.

One other thing to note is that in the same moves toward Windows Phone 8.1, I also changed my Portable Class Library to target both WP8.1 and Xamarin (iOS and Android).

I haven't been able to get any debug results because any time I start it debugging, it fails with "The app didn't start" error. No exceptions are thrown in the output, even when running the Native/Mixed debuggers. Also, no breakpoints get triggered, even in the App constructor.

[I have read that this could be caused by permissions issues.](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-8/fix-windows-8-app-opens-closes/) I have checked and double checked all permissions in the prescribed places and registry entries and found no deviations.

One other thing I should note is that this seems to *only happen with my application*. All other apps seem to run fine.

Comment: You're providing zero useful information here, so there is nothing to answer. You should create a repro-sample, and upload it to Microsoft Connect instead.

Comment: I just figured it out. Apparently I had an `app.config` file that nuget recently decided to update (after I updated some packages) and that caused the error. Excluding it fixed the issue.

Comment: Also, as a note, I was provided near zero useful information from the error being thrown and no exceptions were being thrown either (as mentioned in the post). As such my only recourse was to provide my debugging process including research into what could have caused it and what possible causes that I had crossed off the list. In the future it would be helpful for the OS to give some more informative error codes (both in VS and the Event Logs), but until that point sometimes we aren't given much information to go on.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! Based on what I read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fd4163fe-41c1-4c23-bc8d-be20cc5a70c3/error-code-the-app-didnt-start?forum=winappswithcsharp), the issue was with a file `app.config` in my project.

From what I've been able to see, `app.config` seems to be entirely superfluous. I believe it to be a relic from original Windows 8 applications. I haven't had any issue with it up until now, when it seems Nuget changed the contents of it to reflect some updated app packages.

Excluding this file from the project solved the issue.